# Kafka Consumer committing manually based on a condition.

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

@kafkaListener consumer is commiting once a specific condition is met. Let us say a topic gets the following data from a producer
"Message 0" at offset[0]
"Message 1" at offset[1]

They are received at the consumer and commited with help of acknowledgement.acknowledge()

then the below messages come to the topic

"Message 2" at offset[2]
"Message 3" at offset[3]

The consumer which is running receive the above data. Here condition fail and the above offsets are not committed.

Even if new data comes at the topic, then also "Message 2" and "Message 3" should be picked up by any consumer from the same consumer group as they are not committed. But this is not happening,the consumer picks up a new message.

When I restart my consumer then I get back Message2 and Message3. This should have happened while the consumers were running.

The code is as follows -:
KafkaConsumerConfig file

```
enter code here

@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.setBatchListener(true);
factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group1");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,"1");
        return propsMap;
    }

    @Bean
    public Listener listener() {
        return new Listener();
    }
}

Listner Class
public class Listener {
    public CountDownLatch countDownLatch0 = new CountDownLatch(3);
    private Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);
    static int count0 =0;


    @KafkaListener(topics = "abcdefghi", group = "group1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenPartition0(String data, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,
                                 @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws InterruptedException {
        count0 = count0 + 1;
        LOGGER.info("start consumer 0");

        LOGGER.info("received message via consumer 0='{}' with partition-offset='{}'", data, partitions + "-" + offsets);
        if (count0%2 ==0)
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        LOGGER.info("end of consumer 0");


    }
```

How can i achieve my desired result?

Comment: How long are you waiting? It can take some time for the bad consumer to time out of the group and for the rebalancing to occur

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. The `offset` is a number which is pretty easy to keep tracking in the memory on consumer instance. We need offsets commited for newly arrived consumers in the group for the same partitions. That's why it works as expected when you restart an application or when rebalance happens for the group.

To make it working as you would like you should consider to implement `ConsumerSeekAware` in your listener and call `ConsumerSeekCallback.seek()` for the offset you would like to star consume from the next poll cycle.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/html/_reference.html#seek:

```
public class Listener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    private final ThreadLocal<ConsumerSeekCallback> seekCallBack = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        this.seekCallBack.set(callback);
    }

    @KafkaListener()
    public void listen(...) {
        this.seekCallBack.get().seek(topic, partition, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I implement ConsumerSeekAware with @kafkaListener?

Comment: See a sample in my answer.

Comment: This works, I also had one more doubt, for my use case I would want to pause the Kafka Consumer and resume it from a specific offset when a certain condition is met.
How do I implement consumer.pause() in kafkaListener. 
Could i also programm the kafka listener such that it would pool data only when a certain condition is met and not pool the data as soon as the condition fails?
Thanks

Comment: To pause the consumer you should use `Consumer` argument on your `@KafkaListener` and `seek()` offset before pausing anyway.

Comment: Can you please give an example on how do I add consumer argument on @KafkaListener.
I tried  
@KafkaListener(topics = "abcdefghi", group = "group1", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listenPartition0(String data, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions,@Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets, Acknowledgment acknowledgment, Consumer consumer)

This throws out an error that Failed to convert message payload '[lll]' to 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer

Thanks for the help